# How to get the dimensions of an image after it has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I’m trying to make my image more reliable / responsive in a modal.

and I’m pulling the image source from my database (MySQL) and show the image on a modal.

I have this code:

```
<a class='modal-trigger' href='#view-image' onclick='getImage(`<?php image source; ?>`)'></a>
```

After that this is my JavaScript

```
    function getImage(imgsrc){
      $("#item-thumb").attr("src",imgsrc);
      var height = $('#item-thumb').height();
      if(height > '600'){
        console.log(height);
      }else{
        console.log(height);
      } 
    }
```

My problem is when I’m getting the height of the image it always outputs 0. I think the script itself is getting only the blank image, I suppose? Is there any other way to get the dimension of an image using jQuery?

Comment: im sorry that's <img id='item-thumb'>

Comment: You should compare the height numerically. `height > '600'` implies an alphabetical comparison. Use `height > 600`.

Comment: Yes i tried that but every time i console.log the height it only shows 0

Comment: That wasn’t supposed to give you a solution; it was just a hint.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to pass string to javascript using single quotes `'`, you are passing with back ticks.

corect

```
<a class='modal-trigger' href='#view-image' onclick='getImage(`<?php image source; ?>`)'></a>
```

To:

```
<a class='modal-trigger' href='#view-image' onclick="getImage('<?php image source;?>')"></a>
```

Also, what is the purpose of `href='#view-image'`.

Are you changing the hash on click of link or calling `onclick` event?

Comment: done with it. my problem now is whenever i upload a picture with a large height. it overlaps the page. i wanted to have a condition for the height

Comment: the href='view-image' is for the modal.

Answer (score 0):

If u need to get the image height then u need to render the image on dom (document) unless , u can't get the image height

If u have image data on database, then do the height operation using `PHP`

`list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("image_name.jpg");`

Comment: if u have any doubts let me know

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the image to load before getting its height. Try using this code:

```
$('#item-thumb').load(function () {
  console.log($(this).height());
});
```